# Shift running X window (display environment) on SSH X11 forwarding

Tags: ssh, x11, remote-access, forwarding

I want to see remotely some running GUI application without kill the current process, I have tried vnc and xrdp, xrdp opens a new blank session, so it is not for me, vnc is good, but not exactly what I need, it uses the screen and devices presents, someone could mess with me moving the mouse or typing on the keyboard.

Therefore I figured out the only way I could do what I need is managing to shift a running X window from one display to another, thus even on a SSH -X (X11 forwarding) I would be able to see it.

I am on this quest for a long time and I didn't found out a conclusive solution, that is the reason I am appealing to you. Could you help me to solve this trouble?

Thanks,

Comment: This is a duplicate to http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152291/31673

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used it myself, but [Xpra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpra) appears to be the commonly suggested solution; you might also consider [xmove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmove). Both of these work by proxying the X client's connection to its server, and keeping track of enough state so that you can switch the proxy's server-side connection among servers and get a sensible result. Without such a proxy, as in "stock" X, it is not possible to disconnect a client from one server and connect it to another, except in the case of a client which is designed specifically to support such behavior.

Comment: Very thank you, it is exactly what I was looking for, I don't believe such a good thing is not so spread as it deserves, you worth a medal.

Comment: @TiagoPimenta Well, don't think too much of me for it; I just googled "move existing x11 window to new display" and poked around a little based on the first result. But I'm glad to have been of help!

Comment: While I did not find `xmove` in Debian, `xpra` seems to be supported on Ubuntu and Debian.  On Wheezy be sure to use `apt-get install -t wheezy-backports xpra`, because the stone old version in `wheezy` (main repos) barely works

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Wikipedia page on the subject there are several apps mentioned.

#### [Xmove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmove)

*excerpt*

> xmove is a computer program that allows the movement of X Window
>   System applications between different displays and the persistence of
>   X applications across X server restarts.[4] It solves a problem in the
>   design of X, where an X client (an X application) is tied to the X
>   server (X display) it was started on for its lifetime. Also, if the X
>   server is shut down, the client application is forced to stop running.
>
> xmove lets the client disconnect from its current X server, and
>   connect to a new one, at any time. The transition is completely
>   transparent to the client. xmove works by acting as a proxy between
>   the client and server. It is a "pseudoserver" which stores enough
>   server state so that clients can connect to a new server without being
>   disrupted.

#### [Xpra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpra)

*excerpt*

> xpra or X Persistent Remote Applications is a tool which allows you to
>   run X clients usually on a remote host and then direct their display
>   to your local machine without losing any state.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmove)
>
> It differs from standard X forwarding in that it allows disconnection
>   and reconnection without disrupting the forwarded application. It
>   differs from VNC and similar remote display technologies in that xpra
>   is rootless: i.e., applications forwarded by xpra appear on your
>   desktop as normal windows managed by your window manager, rather than
>   being all "trapped in a box together". Xpra also uses a custom
>   protocol that is self-tuning and relatively latency-insensitive, and
>   thus is usable over worse links than standard X.

#### [Guievict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guievict)

*excerpt*

> guievict is a computer program which enables the GUI of any
>   application for XFree86 implementation of X Window to be transparently
>   migrated to or replicated on another display. Unlike some program
>   providing similar functionalities, it requires neither prearranging
>   steps such as re-linking the application program binary nor
>   re-directing the application process's window system communication
>   through a proxy like xmove does.
>
> Guievict is based on a small X server extension that enables an
>   application to retrieve its window state from the X server and a
>   library of GUI migration functionality that is injected in the
>   application process at run time. Code injection or runtime
>   code-patching can be done via the DynInst API. However, guievict
>   contains its own implementation to avoid requiring users to install
>   DynInst.

Of the 3 of these, Guievict sounds like what you're looking for, mainly that it can checkpoint the state of X application AppX and migrate it to another X server where it can be restored.

(This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152309/31673) comes from slm at unix.stackexchange)